# Payment system NZ Silverstripe for invoice

Tags: payment, silverstripe

I like to create a payment system in my SilverStripe website. It's not an ecommerce. I like that my client can pay their invoice online.
Anyone know a plug-in that I can use like document system with payment?

Comment: SilverStripe Omnipay is a good wrapper for different payment gateways.

Comment: thanks, I will try.